# Interact with UI controls of Windows Store apps

Tags: user-interface, windows-store-apps, windows-10, ui-automation, autoit

I am not able to identify UI controls of Windows Store apps using [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm). The standard app Calculator for example (Windows 10):

[image: Not able to identify the button number 8]

As you can see, it doesn't show information for button `8`. I tried both x86 and x64 versions.

How to interact with Windows Store apps? For traditional desktop apps AutoIt works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible, AutoIt developers have no plans to support UI Automation API. You can find `Inspect.exe` in your Windows SDK and run it in UIA mode to compare with AutoIt Info tool.

There are some other tools supporting UIA (TestStack.White (C#), Winium.Desktop (C#) and some direct UIA wrappers on other languages like [pyuiautomation](https://github.com/zerg-rush/pyuiautomation) on Python). [pywinauto 0.6.0](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/tag/0.6.0) added MS UI Automation support.

UIA support for AutoIt; [24 Apr 2009 AutoIt forum thread](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/80556-autoit-support-for-wpf-and-net-35-applications/). Plans may have changed, but it's the top result for a `"AutoIt WPF support"` Google search.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use Autoit Window info tool in Win10 you should use 64bit version exe.

> Au3Info_x64.exe

Common location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Au3Info_x64.exe`

Comment: It will not help for Store apps because they don't have classic native windows having non-null `hwnd`. Only UI Automation API and its wrappers can help here.